# Django, "render" returns a POST request and not GET after a POST request

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm having my view

```py
def my_wishlist(request):
    user = request.user
    user_products = WishlistProductPrices.objects.filter(user=user).all()
    
    ### Create filters ###
    filter = get_user_filter_fields_wishlist(user_products)
    filter = filter(request.GET,queryset = user_products)

    if request.method == "POST":
        post_form = MyForm(request.POST)    
        if post_form.is_valid():
            #do stuff
            form = MyForm()
            context = {
            "form":form,
            "filter":filter
            }

            return render(request, "myapp/add_wishlist.html",context=context) #Returns POST, seems like
        else:
            #invalid post_form
            context = {
                "form":post_form,
                "filter":filter
            }
            return render(request, "myapp/add_wishlist.html",context=context)        
    else: #Get request
        form = MyForm()
        context = {
            "form":form,
            "filter":filter
        }
        
    return render(request, "myapp/add_wishlist.html",context=context)
```

it works like a charm, but after the user has submitted something, and presses F5 the "do you want to resend the information again" pops-up.

I find it weird, since I assume the `render(request,"mypp/add_wishlist.html)` ad the bottom of the page would return a GET request?

Comment: No, that is why you should return a `redirect`.

Comment: See the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` simply renders the template, and wraps this in a `HttpResponse` and returns that as response to the HTTP request, regardless what that request is.

This means that if the form is valid, and you render a response back, then refreshing will normally make the same HTTP request. This thus means that a person who makes an order can for example make a second order by just refreshing the webpage.

As a result in case of a *successful* request (so where the form is valid), one implements the [*Post/Redirect/Get* architectural pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). In that case, it does not render a template, but it returns a redirect response (a response with status code 302), and thus asks the browser to make a GET request to the passed url.

You can make such redirect with the [**`redirect(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Comment: Thanks! Can I parse on the "context" along wiht the redirect since that contains the `filter` a user has set?I Assume I just redirect to the same page

Comment: @CutePoison: no there is no context that you can pass. You should use the database, the session, cookies, etc. or some other item to persist data until (at least) the next request.

Comment: So the filter I'll need to parse on has to be set in a cookie? Gotcha

Comment: @CutePoison: I would not use a cookie no, usually a database record, or session data is used, since then the data remains at the server side.